# Announcement system with TweenPosition not animating or displaying message

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to make an announcement system where a GUI comes out of the side of the screen which says the player name (the one who sent it) and their message. Although it is not animating or displaying the message or the player name even though there are no errors in the output.

```
--declare the admins
local admins = {
    ["adminnamehere"] = true
}
local AnnouncementGUI = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Frame
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Chatted:Connect(function(message)
        if admins[player.Name] then
            --split the message of the "!msg" prefix and the announcement
            local words = string.split(message, " ")
            local command = string.lower(words[1])
            if command == "!msg" then
                AnnouncementGUI:TweenPosition(
                    UDim2.new(0, 275, 0, 109),
                    "Out",
                    "Quart",
                    5,
                    false
                )
                -- get rid of the prefix ("!msg")
                message:gsub(words[1], "")
                -- show on the gui who sent the message
                AnnouncementGUI.SenderName.Text = player.Name
                -- show on the gui the message
                AnnouncementGUI.Message.Text = message
            end
        end
    end)
end)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All GUI animations should be done on the client, therefor you need to fire a remote with the `senderName`, `text` and so on to every client in the game and update the GUI locally for each player.

**TLDR**; GUI modifications done on the server *will not* update for the client, as such you need to use remotes to fire the client/clients and have a `LocalScript` update the GUI locally.